# Laplace transform $f(t)f'(t)$

Tags: definite-integrals, laplace-transform

I am interested in the laplace transform of $f(t)f'(t)$. If it is known that there is no solution to this then there will be a pretty short answer however I would like to know if one exists and if so what it is.

I tried to find a solution using integration by parts:
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\mathscr{L}\{f(t)f'(t)\}&=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}f(t)f'(t)\ dt \\
&=\big[f(t)e^{-st}f(t)\big]_0^{\infty}-\int_0^{\infty}f(t)(-se^{-st}f(t)+e^{-st}f'(t))\ dt \\
&=\big[f(t)e^{-st}f(t)\big]_0^{\infty}-\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}f(t)f'(t)\ dt+\int_0^{\infty}se^{-st}f(t)^2\ dt \\
2\mathscr{L}\{f(t)f'(t)\}&=-f(0)^2+\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}f(t)^2\ dt \\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

From this I evaluated $\mathscr{L}\{f(t)^2\}$
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\mathscr{L}\{f(t)^2\}&=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}f(t)^2\ dt \\
&=\bigg[-\frac{1}{s}e^{-st}f(t)^2\bigg]_0^{\infty}-\int_0^{\infty}-\frac{1}{s}e^{-st}\times 2f(t)f'(t)\ dt \\
&=\bigg[-\frac{1}{s}e^{-st}f(t)^2\bigg]_0^{\infty}+\frac{2}{s}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}f(t)f'(t)\ dt \\
&=\frac{f(0)^2}{s}+\frac{2}{s}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}f(t)f'(t)\ dt \\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

I then substituted this back into the expression for $\mathscr{L}\{f(t)f'(t)\}$ to get
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
2\mathscr{L}\{f(t)f'(t)\}&=-f(0)^2+\frac{f(0)^2}{s}+\frac{2}{s}\mathscr{L}\{f(t)f'(t)\} \\
\bigg(2-\frac{2}{s}\bigg)\mathscr{L}\{f(t)f'(t)\}&=-f(0)^2+\frac{f(0)^2}{s} \\
\mathscr{L}\{f(t)f'(t)\}&=\frac{f(0)^2}{2(s-1)}-\frac{sf(0)^2}{2(s-1)} \\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

This seems odd as a solution to me as it doesn't have any functions of the form $\mathscr{L}\{f(t)\}$. I also am aware that it is wrong due to it not working for basic functions such as $e^x$ etc.

Essentially my question is:

What was wrong about my method, and is there a known expression for $\mathscr{L}\{f(t)f'(t)\}?$

Comment: I would observe $$f(t)f'(t) = \frac{1}{2} \left(2f(t)f'(t) \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left( f(t)^2 \right)'$$, and I'd start the process again.

Comment: Also in your first integration by parts you forgot an $s$ factor.

Comment: @user8469759 Okay will do, thanks :p

Comment: @user8469759 Agh you're right, and by putting it back in results in $0=0$, annoying!

Comment: If you want to know about the existance just work out what conditions you need on $(f^2)'$, which is probably easier.